# PHP, How to secure GET variable from URL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is URL:

http://ex.com/members.php?id=5320

Here is code:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * from members where id='$_GET[id]'");
```

which method is secure?

Comment: Don't ever use `$_GET` directly in a query. You firstly have to sanitize it.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi (as you appear to be) then use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: You can try `WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"])` but `mysqli_*` functions with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) is better.

Comment: Use [_Prepared Statements_](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) on MySQLi and you don't have to worry about injections.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You can use prepared statements with either MySQLi or with PDO; I've added a link to my answer that shows how to secure queries with both extensions

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and bind variables when you're using MySQLi

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * from members where id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

You may also wish to validate that `$_GET['id']` is an integer first, and return an error message if it isn't rather than have all the overhead of a db query to return nothing.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) to a previous question to understand why yu should take this approach

Comment: I also recommand using the [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: Also make sure $_GET['id'] exists with `isset()` or `!empty()` to prevent undefined errors.